# Simple SQL Pivot returning null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having one of those days.

I am trying to pivot the data below into columns

```
  ID | SplitString
-------------------
|  1 | ABC 
|  2 | ABC03082017
|  3 | 03082017
|  4 | 1
|  5 | TestData
```

So far I have the code below but when I run it, it is returning nulls, the columns have the correct header but the data is all null.

```
    select * 
from 
(
    select ID,splitData from dbo.fn_splitstring(@RawData_Header, '|')
) src
pivot
(
    MAX(ID) for splitData in ([Identifier], [ProviderCode], [FileDate],[Code],[FileName])
) piv;
```

The first part of the pivot script is working correctly and returning the table above.

EDIT**

I am trying to return the data similar to the image below

[image]

Thanks for your help

Noelle

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: This is returning `NULL` because there are no rows with values `[Identifier], [ProviderCode], [FileDate],[Code],[FileName]` in column `splitData`. What are you trying to achive?

Comment: @Kannan I have added an image of the desired results. Thanks

Comment: @Rokuto I thought the line "splitData in ([Identifier], [ProviderCode], [FileDate],[Code],[FileName])" was to give the column names for the pivoted data?

Comment: No, in `SELECT` you are naming your columns. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `PIVOT`, you have to change your code to:

```
 select [1] AS [Identifier], [2] AS [ProviderCode], [3] AS [FileDate], [4] AS [Code], [5] AS [FileName]
from 
(
    select ID,splitData from dbo.fn_splitstring(@RawData_Header, '|')
) src
pivot
(
    MAX(splitData) for Id in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) piv;
```

Read more about [`PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the links. That worked perfectly. I have much more complex pivots to do as part of this functionality the links will be a great help.